# AWS Cloudwatch = Filter Events by EventID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

How do you filter events in a log stream by EventID?

[image]

I want to find all events with EventID X (where X is an integer number)

The events have a field for the EventID in this format: `<EventID>X</EventID>`

I have tried the following filters, but none of them work:

```
EventID X
EventID=X
EventID:X
{"EventID":"X"}
{"EventID":X}
"EventID":"X"
"EventID":X
{"$.eventId":"X"}
{$.eventid=X}
<EventID>X</EventID>
```

It sounds like a super simple and obvious case, but I cannot find anything similar on the AWS docs/forums or on StackOverflow or anywhere else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close :)

`"<EventID>X</EventID>"` did the trick.

Comment: does this still work for you? I tried that syntax and it is not working. Are you putting it directly in the "Filter events" search box from your screen shot?